# Is it the right way to do union query after joins in rails 3.2?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are 3 models `log` (which belongs to customer), `customer` and `project` in `rails 3.2` app. Both `customer` and `project` have `sales_id` field. Here is the query we want to do:

return the following logs for customers 1) logs for customers whose sales_id is equal to session[:user_id] and 2) logs for customers whose projects' sales_id is equal to session[:user_id]

The rails query for 1) could be:

```
Log.joins(:customer).where(:customers => {:sales_id => session[:user_id]})
```

Rails query for 2) could be:

```
Log.joins(:customer => :projects).where(:projects => {:sales_id => session[:user_id})
```

To combine the queries above, is it the right way to do the following?

```
Log.joins([:customer, {:customer => :projects}]).where('customers.sales_id = id OR projects.sales_id = id', id: session[:user_id])
```

Chapter 11.2.4 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html talks about an interesting query case. We haven't tested the query above yet. We would like to know if the union query above is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't support union natively. In your case, I think it doesn't need union, just use left outer join.

```
Log.joins('left outer JOIN `customers` ON `customers`.`id` = `logs`.`customer_id`
left outer JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`').where('customers.sales_id = :id OR projects.sales_id = :id', id: session[:user_id]).distinct
```

Comment: You are right that rails does not support union natively. The rails query is sometime more elegant than raw sql and is powerful as well.

Comment: Yes, Active Record is most powerful and elegant tool I have seen in various languages. If it can support more join types, It will be greater, it supports inner join natively only, if I want left outer join or others, I must write some sql fragments.

Comment: Is there a solution with rails query? I am trying to use rails query to do the sql.

Comment: If you must run "union" in rails, you can see the gem union, https://github.com/tsmango/union, I haven't used it. A few days ago, I knew a gem named "squeel", it let you write sql easier except "union". You can check it https://github.com/ernie/squeel.